# Expression for $p(\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{d})$ and the respective Markov Network

Tags: independence, graphical-model

I would like to check if I correctly derived my the expression for $p(\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{d})$. Here's the question:

> Consider a model of diseases and symptoms. $s_i\in\{0,1\}$ is a binary random variable indicating whether the patient is showing the $i$-th symptom and $d_j\in \{0,1\}$ is a binary random variable indicating whether the patient has $j$-th disease. A model for this is given by $$p(\mathbf{s,d})=\frac{1}{Z}\exp(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{d})$$

where $Z$ is the normalisation constant and $\mathbf{W},\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ are the parameters of the model.

I would like to draw the Markov Network for this model. Assume there are $n$ total symptoms and $m$ total diseases.

[image]

**Question 1:** Would this Markov Network be correct? Since it's a Markov Network, I don't have arrows, otherwise if it was a belief network, here's how I would draw it:

[image]

**Question 2** Would this belief network be correct?

So now, I have the question:

> Derive the expression for $p(\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{d})$. Is this distribution factorised?

Here's my solution:

$$p(\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{d}) = \frac{p(\mathbf{s},\mathbf{d})}{p(\mathbf{d})} = \frac{\exp\left(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{d}\right)}{\sum_{\mathbf{s}}\exp\left(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{d}\right)} =  \frac{\exp\left(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}\right)}{\sum_{\mathbf{s}}\exp\left(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}\right)} \\ \propto
\exp\left(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{s}\right)
= \exp(\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{W}d+\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{a}) =  \exp(\mathbf{s}^T(\mathbf{W}\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a})) = \\ \exp\left(\sum_i^n\mathcal{1}_{\{s_i=1\}}\sum_j^m W_{ij}d_j+a_i\right) \\ \prod^n_i \exp(\sum_j^mW_{ij}d_j+a_i) = \prod_i^np(s_i|\mathbf{d})
$$

The distribution is factoried and $p(s_i|\mathbf{d}) = \sigma(a_i+\sum_jW_{ij}d_j)$ where $\sigma(x) = e^x/(1+e^x)$

Is my derivation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sv}{\mathbf{s}}
\newcommand{\dv}{\mathbf{d}}
\newcommand{\Wv}{\mathbf{W}}
\newcommand{\av}{\mathbf{a}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\pperp}{\perp\kern-5pt\perp}
\newcommand{\npperp}{\not\perp\kern-8pt\perp}
$
**Your first question**:
The probability $p(\mathbf s, \mathbf d)$ can be rewritten as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\sv, \dv) &= \frac{1}{Z}\exp\left(\sv^T\Wv \dv + \av^T\sv + \bv^T\dv\right)\\
    &= \frac{1}{Z}\prod_{ik}\exp(s_iW_{ik}d_k)\prod_r\exp(a_rs_r)\prod_{j}\exp(b_jd_j).
\end{align}
$$
Thus, you obtain exactly the factorization depicted by your Markov network (MN). There is an edge between $s_i$ and $d_k$ if and only if $W_{ik}\ne 0$.

**Your second question**:
We know now that your MN is describing conditional independence relation (CI) in a generic pdf of the given type, i.e. if the MN has a connection between two nodes, this would in the generic case yield dependence between the corresponding random variables. In particular, we deduce from the MN that in general:
$$
\left(d_i \npperp d_k\right).
$$
But in your belief network (BN), all the $s_r$ are colliders, thus the BN would require:
$$
\left(d_i \pperp d_k\right), \quad i\ne k.
$$
Therefore, your BN is not suitable in the sense that it is not an I-map for the generic pdf of the given family.

**Your third question**:
The fact that $p(\sv|\dv)$ factors in $\sv$ follows from the MN. Conditioning on $\dv$ completely separates this bipartite graph, so all the $d_i$ are independent, i.e. the pdf factors. Your derivation in formulas appears quite right, although I am a bit confused about the term $1_{s_i=1}$ and that the variable $\sv$ disappeared from the second to last expression. So I would suggest the following, slightly changed version of your derivation:
Following you, I will consider only factors containing $s_i$ and combine all factors containing $d_i$ into the overall constant factor:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\sv|\dv) &= \frac{p(\sv, \dv)}{p(\dv)}\\
    &\propto \exp\left( \sv^T\Wv\dv + \av^T\sv\right)\\
    &= \exp\left(\sv^T(\Wv\dv + \av) \right)\\
    &= \prod_i \exp(s_i(\Wv\dv + \av)_i)\\
    &= \prod_i f_i(s_i).
\end{align}
$$
This confirms that $p(\sv|\dv)$ does indeed factor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I agree I wrote confusing/unnecessary notation, but our answers are the same in the end. Actually the fact that I know $p(\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{d})=\prod_ip(s_i|\mathbf{d})$  where $p(s_i|\mathbf{d}) = \sigma(a_i+\sum_jW_{ij}d_j)$ where $\sigma(x) = e^x/(1+e^x)$ is because there's an identical problem in BRML (exercise 4.4) and I wanted to double check their answer. Also if you don't mind taking a look at [this Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584819/deriving-the-expression-for-p-mathcalk-where-mathcalk-mathbfs), it should take very quick to answer imo